Instrumenting Async functions in rust
I'm trying to create a procedural macro to be applied on functions in my rust code. The macro implements logic to instrument and gather metrics on the applied method. I want to implement a metric counter for successful and failed method calls. Here's what I have at the moment:
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn collect_metrics(_attr: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let item_clone = item.clone();

    let input = parse_macro_input!(item_clone as ItemFn);
    let fn_name = &input.sig.ident;
    let block = &input.block;
    let attrs = &input.attrs;
    let vis = &input.vis;
    let sig = &input.sig;

    let is_async = sig.asyncness.is_some();

    validate_macro_func_response(sig, item); // validates function return type is a Result

    // Generate a new function with metrics collection
    let expanded = quote! {
        #(#attrs)*
        #vis #sig {
            use crate::otel::metrics::METRICS;
            
            if let Some(metrics) = METRICS.get() {
                info!("Collecting Metrics...");

                let start = std::time::Instant::now();

                metrics.request_counter.add(
                    1,  
                    &[
                        opentelemetry::KeyValue::new("_otel_function", stringify!(#fn_name)),
                    ],
                );

                let result = (|| #block)();

                // Record the duration
                metrics.request_duration.record(
                    start.elapsed().as_secs_f64(),
                    &[
                        opentelemetry::KeyValue::new("_otel_function", stringify!(#fn_name)),
                    ],
                );

                result
            }
            else {
                (|| #block)()
            }
        }
    };

    // Convert the expanded code into a TokenStream
    TokenStream::from(expanded)
}


This works fine. However, when I try to add a match on the result to increment my success and failed counters, something like this:
match &result {
    Ok(_) => {
        metrics.success_counter.add(
            1,
            &[
                opentelemetry::KeyValue::new("_otel_function", stringify!(#fn_name)),
            ],
        );
    },
    Err(_) => {
        metrics.error_counter.add(
            1,
            &[
                opentelemetry::KeyValue::new("_otel_function", stringify!(#fn_name)),
            ],
        );
    },
}

I get this error:
 ------------- the expected `async` block
172 |     #[collect_metrics]
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |     |
    |     expected `Pin<Box<...>>`, found `Result<_, _>`
    |     this expression has type `&Pin<Box<{async block@../grpc/handler.rs:171:5: 171:18}>>`
    |     in this procedural macro expansion
    |
   ::: ../otel-proc-macro/src/lib.rs:49:1
    |
49  | pub fn collect_metrics(_attr: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- in this expansion of `#[collect_metrics]`
    |
    = note: expected struct `Pin<Box<{async block@../grpc/handler.rs:171:5: 171:18}>>`
                 found enum `Result<_, _>`

This seems to happen when the function being decorated is an async function.
Here's how the macro is being used:

#[tonic::async_trait]
impl LoomService for LoomServiceImpl {

    #[instrument]
    #[collect_metrics]
    async fn pre_transaction_screening(
        &self,
        request: Request<PreTransactionScreenRequest>,
    ) -> Result<Response<PreTransactionScreenResponse>, Status> {
        // method body
    }

}

Any idea what I could be doing wrong? What's the best way to intercept the function result and increment my success and error counters regardless if the function is sync or async?
I tried different approaches. Nothing seems to work.

You most certainly don't want an immediately invoked closure (|| #block)() since it's not async. Try just #block or maybe { #block }.

noted!! what i'm trying to do is get the result of the executed function block. and then run a match to increment success or error counters depending on the result. is this possible?

Should be, however your errors include references to Pin<Box<...>> which indicates that you don't have normal async methods and are using something like #[async_trait] that is changing things from under you. Can you show a sample of where you're using your #[collect_metrics] attribute?

Yeah. i'm using tonic's async_trait. here's a sample usage (sorry about the formatting. couldn't get it to look nicer in the comment):
#[tonic::async_trait]
impl LoomService for LoomServiceImpl {

    #[instrument]
    #[collect_metrics]
    async fn transaction_screening(
        &self,
        request: Request<PreTransactionScreenRequest>,
    ) -> Result<Response<PreTransactionScreenResponse>, Status> {

     // method body...
    }


edit that into your post please - not just for formatting but also so the target usage is clear.
